# Flutter Linear progress indicator for each page of pageview builder

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout, flutter-animation

I want to build a progress indicator for each page of the pageview builder. Pageview changes after 10 seconds and the progress bar shifts to the next bar. I have successfully implemented this, but encounter an issue of 4 bars loading at the same time, while going back and forth to the page view screen or when I minimize and reopen the app.

This is what I already have achieved with the following code:

[image]

This is my code:

```
class WelcomeScreen extends StatefulWidget {
  const WelcomeScreen({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  State<WelcomeScreen> createState() => _WelcomeScreenState();
}

class _WelcomeScreenState extends State<WelcomeScreen>
    with TickerProviderStateMixin {
  final WelcomeController controller = Get.put(WelcomeController());

  late AnimationController animationControllerOne;
  late AnimationController animationControllerTwo;
  late AnimationController animationControllerThree;
  late AnimationController animationControllerFour;
  late Animation<double> animation;

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    animationControllerOne =
        AnimationController(duration: const Duration(seconds: 10), vsync: this);
    animation = Tween(begin: 0.0, end: 1.0).animate(animationControllerOne)
      ..addListener(() {
        setState(() {
        });
      });
    animationControllerOne.forward();
    animationControllerTwo =
        AnimationController(duration: const Duration(seconds: 10), vsync: this);
    animation = Tween(begin: 1.0, end: 2.0).animate(animationControllerTwo)
      ..addListener(() {
        setState(() {
        });
      });
    Timer(const Duration(seconds: 10), () {
      animationControllerTwo.forward();
    });

    animationControllerThree =
        AnimationController(duration: const Duration(seconds: 10), vsync: this);
    animation = Tween(begin: 2.0, end: 3.0).animate(animationControllerThree)
      ..addListener(() {
        setState(() {});
      });
    Timer(const Duration(seconds: 20), () {
      animationControllerThree.forward();
    });
    animationControllerFour =
        AnimationController(duration: const Duration(seconds: 10), vsync: this);
    animation = Tween(begin: 3.0, end: 4.0).animate(animationControllerFour)
      ..addListener(() {
        setState(() {});
      });
    Timer(const Duration(seconds: 30), () {
      animationControllerFour.forward();
    });

    animationControllerFour.addStatusListener((status) {
      if (status == AnimationStatus.completed) {
        animationControllerOne.reset();
        animationControllerTwo.reset();
        animationControllerThree.reset();
        animationControllerFour.reset();
        animationControllerOne.forward();
      }
      animationControllerOne.addStatusListener((status) {
        if (status == AnimationStatus.completed) {
          animationControllerTwo.reset();
          animationControllerTwo.forward();
        }
      });
      animationControllerTwo.addStatusListener((status) {
        if (status == AnimationStatus.completed) {
          animationControllerThree.reset();
          animationControllerThree.forward();
        }
      });
      animationControllerThree.addStatusListener((status) {
        if (status == AnimationStatus.completed) {
          animationControllerFour.reset();
          animationControllerFour.forward();
        }
      });
    });
  }

  @override
  void dispose() {
    animationControllerOne.dispose();
    animationControllerTwo.dispose();
    animationControllerThree.dispose();
    animationControllerFour.dispose();
    super.dispose();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      backgroundColor: context.theme.scaffoldBackgroundColor,
      appBar: AppBar(
        systemOverlayStyle: SystemUiOverlayStyle(
          statusBarColor: Get.isDarkMode ? darkBackground : lightBackground,
          statusBarIconBrightness:
              Get.isDarkMode ? Brightness.light : Brightness.dark,
        ),
        title: Padding(
          padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 16),
          child: Row(
            key: const Key('loading bar'),
            children: [
              Expanded(
                child: LinearProgressIndicator(
                  color: primaryBlue,
                  backgroundColor: const Color(0xFFD9D9D9),
                  minHeight: 8,
                  value: animationControllerOne.value,
                ),
              ),
              const SizedBox(
                width: 10,
              ),
              Expanded(
                child: LinearProgressIndicator(
                  color: primaryBlue,
                  backgroundColor: const Color(0xFFD9D9D9),
                  minHeight: 8,
                  value: animationControllerTwo.value,
                ),
              ),
              const SizedBox(
                width: 10,
              ),
              Expanded(
                child: LinearProgressIndicator(
                  color: primaryBlue,
                  backgroundColor: const Color(0xFFD9D9D9),
                  minHeight: 8,
                  value: animationControllerThree.value,
                ),
              ),
              const SizedBox(
                width: 10,
              ),
              Expanded(
                child: LinearProgressIndicator(
                  backgroundColor: const Color(0xFFD9D9D9),
                  color: primaryBlue,
                  minHeight: 8,
                  value: animationControllerFour.value,
                ),
              ),
            ],
          ),
        ),
        elevation: 0,
        backgroundColor: Get.isDarkMode ? darkBackground : lightBackground,
        centerTitle: true,
      ),
      body: Padding(
        padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(vertical: 15),
        child: Column(
          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
          children: [
            Text(
              'Welcome to Demonstration Bank!'.tr,
              key: const Key('message'),
              textAlign: TextAlign.center,
              style: TextStyle(
                color: Get.isDarkMode ? lightBackground : darkBackground,
                fontSize: Get.height * 0.027,
                fontWeight: FontWeight.w600,
              ),
            ),
            SizedBox(
              height: Get.height * 0.05,
            ),
            SizedBox(
              height: Get.height * 0.4,
              width: Get.width * 0.8,
              child: PageView.builder(
                controller: controller.gifsController,
                physics: const NeverScrollableScrollPhysics(),
                itemCount: controller.images.length,
                scrollDirection: Axis.horizontal,
                itemBuilder: (context, index) {
                  return Image.asset(
                    controller.images[index],
                    fit: BoxFit.fitWidth,
                  );
                },
              ),
            ),
            SizedBox(
              height: Get.height * 0.15,
            ),
            Row(
              mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
              children: [
                CustomButton(
                  key: const Key('sign in button'),
                  height: Get.height * 0.069,
                  width: Get.width * 0.335,
                  fontSize: Get.height * 0.021,
                  color: Get.isDarkMode ? lightBackground : darkBackground,
                  textColor: Get.isDarkMode ? darkBackground : lightBackground,
                  text: 'Sign in'.tr,
                  onPressed: () => Get.to(() => const SigninScreen()),
                ),
                const SizedBox(
                  width: 19,
                ),
                CustomButton(
                  key: const Key('sign up button'),
                  height: Get.height * 0.069,
                  width: Get.width * 0.335,
                  fontSize: Get.height * 0.021,
                  color: primaryBlue,
                  textColor: Colors.white,
                  text: 'Sign Up'.tr,
                  onPressed: () => Get.to(() => CreateAccountScreen()),
                ),
              ],
            ),
            const SizedBox(
              height: 24,
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Unexpected result: ( **Note**: this problem does not happen always )

[image]

Comment: Hello, You did amazing work so far. You can achive same thing which you want without any problem using the package https://pub.dev/packages/story_view. Take a look :)

Comment: Thank you, but I don't want to use the package for this.

Comment: Does it happen without getx